# How to make xml definition to be re-usable (some kind of template)?

Tags: android, xml, viewflipper

My situation is following. I have one `Activity` that contains three main parts. At the top of this activity there is an tools panel with two `ImageButtons`. At the bottom of the activity there is also tools panel similar to top.

Main component of this activity is at the center of the screen which is `LinearLayout` that contains 3x3 `ImageButtons` grid. To get the context I quickly describe purpose of these grid buttons.

This 3x3 grid describes states of this buttons (lets say toggle button and its states are on/off) for particular day. So for one day you have one set of 3x3 and these have its own state for particular day.

Now what I trying to achieve is to have functionality which allows user to scroll between grids or dates respectively. My idea is to have `ViewFlipper` as the main component of the activity (instead of `LinearLayout`) and one or more grid of buttons. This is what I already have. I am able to switch 3x3 to another 3x3 (with states) for another day. For this I simply copy/paste my 3x3 grid XML definition and put this as children to view flipper (x-times).

My idea is to have one definition of 3x3 and reuse it x-times like some kind of template so I will be able to say "I want to have another 3x3 with so and so states for this day and I want it to add this as next child to `ViewFlipper`".

For this purpose (to have component of 3x3) I simply made class which extends `LinearLayour` and within it I want to generate/reuse 3x3 definition for buttons. Sure I am able to do it by java code in this new class but is some way to do it with reusing of xml (which is better to maintain and to read)?

I tried to use `LayoutInflater` but this is probably not what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance

#### Edit

Here is code for main layout with flipper

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/view_flip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000">
    <!-- Here goes 9x9 cubbie layout programaticaly -->
</ViewFlipper>
```

To this fipper I adding view with this layout (this code is assigned via LayoutInflater).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/background" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/life_att_1" style="@style/AttributeButton" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/life_att_text_1" android:text="test"
            style="@style/AttributeText" />
    </LinearLayout>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

#### EDIT 2

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/background" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" android:paddingLeft="16dip">
```

Comment: LayoutInflater sounds good to me. Try putting your 3x3 grid in a seperate XML file and infalte it whenever you need it.

Comment: Thank you `LayoutInflater` works realy good to me. My previous mistake was in wrong use of inflater now works fine (I used code sample from official documentation). I have one issue with this. If I used `<ViewFlipper>my views</ViewFlipper>` directly than it worked fine. But if I use inflater than views in `ViewFlipper` are shrinked little bit. Is this standard behavior or it is issue with my XML code ?

Comment: that shouldn't happen. Must be your xml. Hard to say whats going wrong without the code.

Comment: I edited post and added code examples. For flipper I set background as red and if I load content below I expect that entire flipper screen will be filled by content. Unfortunately there are spaces on left and on the bottom of the flipper's screen (red - flipper background). Thus not all the flipper's area is filled.

Comment: maybe its because of the wrap_content in the last linear layout. But the @color/background should fill the screen as it is. Weird

Comment: Only way I found here is to add paddingLeft attribute to wrapper LinearLayout (please refer to EDIT 2). I do not think that this is right solution but only solution I currently found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I found here is to add paddingLeft attribute to wrapper LinearLayout (please refer to EDIT 2). I do not think that this is right solution but only solution I currently found.